# It is possible to manipulate the 'autocomplete browser data' in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, xhtml

Today I read some posts about the 'autocomplete' browser generated in the text fields, and i was wondering if it's possible to manipulate those results with jQuery, like highlight some part of the results or change the bg color (not that yellow one) or something like that.

I'm not talking about any plug-in 'autocomplete'.

[Here's a example of what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/LM3nE/) (Double click inside the text input and probably will show up some 'emails')

Comment: The title should be It is possible to manipulate the 'browser for data' using JS?

Comment: I would turn autocomplete off for that textbox and implement your own...  here is something I found.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor

Comment: I know that i can 'turn it off' using `$("input").attr("autocomplete","off");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser handles that auto complete. Your page can't edit it. I for example, have it disabled so I don't see anything in the drop down list.

Sort of related:

You can disable it by adding the `autocomplete="off"` property to the input element.